# 2D projection of a 3D model

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, projection

I have a question about Matlab. I have a three dimensional model (*.stl) in Matlab and I want to create some kind of a two dimensional projection. The attached image shows the visualisation of the model by using the patch command. I want to create a two dimensional image/plot from this view on the three dimensional model. This two dimensional projection should have an own x-y-coordinate system, is that possible?

[3D view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sJNF.png)

[New coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POs3f.png)

Comment: "some kind of a two dimensional projection" is as undefined and unaccurate as it gets. Please describe better what you need

Comment: I want to create a view (like shown on the image) with a two dimensional coordinate system from the three dimensional coordinate system.
X, Y, Z --> X', Y'
It is relatively similar to the projection of a three dimensional model on a plane.

Comment: The plot itself project the 3D model onto 2D axes.

Comment: I want to to create a planar view from the given three dimensional image. I want to transform the x,y,z coordinate system into an x',y' system for the planar (2D) view. The shown perspective of the model should be the same. I added a second image to the post, maybe it can help to understand my problem.